# How to remove duplicates from NSIndexSet?

Tags: objective-c, nsindexset

What's the best way to remove duplicate indices from an NSIndexSet? For example, say my NSIndexSet looks like this:

```
[ 1, 3, 3, 6, 7, 12, 12, 12 ]
```

I want it to look like:

```
[ 1, 3, 6, 7, 12 ]
```

What's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: `NSIndexSet`s can't contain duplicate indexes. They're **sets**. From the docs: «The NSIndexSet class represents an immutable collection of ***unique*** unsigned integers,» Please give more details about your problem, because it doesn't seem to be what you think it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSIndexSet` cannot possibly contain duplicates. What makes you think you have any?

To be more specific, the documentation states

> The NSIndexSet class represents an immutable collection of unique unsigned integers, known as **indexes** because of the way they are used. This collection is referred to as an **index** set.

The key point here is the word "unique", which means it cannot contain duplicates. Attempting to add an index to an index set that's already present will result in no change.

Answer (score 1):

NSIndexSet is an immutable class. Also, from the documentation:

> The NSIndexSet class represents an immutable collection of unique unsigned integers, known as indexes because of the way they are used. This collection is referred to as an index set.

Long story short, you do not have any duplicates.

Comment: Immutability is irrelevant. You can always create a mutable copy.

Comment: Of course, but then it wouldn't be an NSIndexSet now, would it?

Comment: Yes it would. An `NSMutableIndexSet` is a subclass of `NSIndexSet`. The assertion "NSMutableIndexSet is an NSIndexSet" is true.

Comment: NSMutableIndexSet inherits from NSIndexSet, and not the other way around.

Comment: No, what you said is "Immutability is irrelevant". It's relevant because being NSIndexSet an immutable class, you can not modify its content. You could create a new NSIndexSet based on another NSIndexSet or create an mutable copy (NSMutableIndexSet) based in its content to modify the content. But an actual NSIndexSet instance 's content can not be modified.

Comment: You're being overly pedantic. If the question was "how do I trim whitespace off of an NSString" would you also claim that you can't because NSString is immutable? You know damn well the question isn't "how do I modify this immutable object".

Comment: I don't really understand your attitude considering the fact that my statement is accurate. If you have an NSIndexSex instance, you will not be able to modify the content of it in its current form. You will need to either create a new instance based on the modification, or create a mutable instance based on that instance. You know this is accurate, so get off your high horse. Your initial statement "Immutability is irrelevant" is inaccurate. And is an important statement for the OP, who was also confused about how set works.

Comment: I think he was referring to your incorrect application of the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Note for posterity (because I don't understand why two nearly-identical answers are 7 apart in terms of score): J2theC's answer contained the doc quote _before_ Kevin's did. Kevin added the quote within the 5-minute grace period, so there is no revision history. His answer originally consisted only of the current first sentence.